# Click event can't be captured

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

Once a icon is clicked a submit button is set to visible. 
But then that button is clicked this does not work ( class of that button- 'edit_forum_reply' )

```
    $('.edit_forum_reply').on("click", function (event) {

   alert("NO RESULT");
     });
```

HTML :

```
    <td style="display: none;" data-id="{{ replyId }}">

        <div id="summernote2" data-id="{{ replyId }}"></div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary edit-forum-reply" style="display:none;"  data-id="{{ replyId }}">Submit</a>
        <a class="btn"  style="display : none;" href="forum/api/topic/" data-id="{{ replyId }}">Cancel</a>

   </td>
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> class of that button- 'edit_forum_reply'

You missed the dot for class selector in the selector for binding event. I also could not see that class in the provided html.

You have use **hyphen** in html `edit-forum-reply` but for binding code you used **underscore** `$('.edit_forum_reply').on`

```
$('.edit-forum-reply').live("click", function (event) {
    alert("NO RESULT");
});
```

The `live()` is deprecated you better use `on()`

```
$('.edit-forum-reply').on("click", function (event) {
    alert("NO RESULT");
});
```

If the element with class `edit_forum_reply` then you need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using on

```
$(document).on("click", '.edit-forum-reply', function (event) {
    alert("NO RESULT");
});
```

Comment: I also could not see that class in the provided html

Comment: You have use hyphen in html edit-forum-reply but for binding code you used underscore $('.edit_forum_reply').on

Comment: Funny though :)
In a hurry. So missed that thanks a lot

Comment: This link has a inline css code as style="display:none;" then how this link  will be appeared in page  <a class="btn btn-primary edit-forum-reply" style="display:none;"  data-id="{{ replyId }}">Submit</a>

Comment: It is set to visible by clicking some other icon

Answer (score 5):

You should be using same class element in html as well as javascript function. Here you were using two different names :

`edit-forum-reply` in HTML and `edit_forum_reply` in JS.  Use the following and this will work.

JS:

```
$(document).on("click",'.edit-forum-reply', function (event) {
    alert("NO RESULT");
});
```

HTML :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary edit-forum-reply" style="display:none;"  data-id="{{ replyId }}">Submit</a>
```

You would need to bind the event to dynamically added content.

Answer (score 1):

Class selector needs a `.`

```
$('.edit_forum_reply')
```

Also, [`live()` is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/live/). Use **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead (unless you're using a very old version of jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, [Live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated.

You should try below code:

```
$('.edit-forum-reply').on("click", function (event) {
    alert("NO RESULT");
});
```